# Prevent onmouseout from firing on child elements

Tags: reactjs

Given the following:

```
render() {

  const onMouseOver = (event) => {
    this.setState({ isHovering: true });
  };

  const onMouseOut = (event) => {
    this.setState({ isHovering: false });
  };

  const open = this.state.isHovering ? true : false;

  return (
    <Nav className={styles.TopNav} bsStyle="pills" activeKey={1}>
      <NavDropdown
        className={dropDownClasses}
        eventKey={1}
        open={open}
        title="Cards"
        id="nav-dropdown"
        onMouseEnter={onMouseOver}
        onMouseOut={onMouseOut}>
        <MenuItem eventKey="1.1">Action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="1.2">Another action</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
      <NavItem className={styles.navLink} eventKey={2}>Blog</NavItem>
    </Nav>
  );
```

How do I prevent onMouseOut firing when the mouse is over a child of NavDropdown.

Can I detect if I am over a child in onMouseOut?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is not React specific. `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble, so the handler also triggers for children of the element. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't bubble.

So you should listen to `mouseleave` instead.

Comment: Thanks. For bonus points you could answer my even more specific question that needs the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047269/how-to-create-a-hover-dropdown-in-react-bootsrap

Comment: Should be closed as a duplicate IMO.

Comment: I've never done that before. I've initiated the process.

Comment: I didn't think it was a duplicate. I have the same need and it would have been nice to have a very specific answer.