# Side menu disappears when you hover over the text inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my problem is that the side menu closes when you hover over the text inside it... The "About" text works properly but the other three don't... I tried different solutions but I can't figure out what's the cause for it. The menu is supposed to open when you hover over the 3 lines, and stay open while you're hovering over it. Please help

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("menubtn").style.color = "transparent";
  document.getElementById("menubtn").style.transition = "0.2s";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#a5a5a5";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("menubtn").style.color = "#ffffff";
  document.getElementById("menubtn").style.transition = "0.6s";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.navbarheader {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.menubtn {
  margin: 14px 0px 0px 23px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 37px;
  transform: scale(1, 0.8);
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  border: none;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbarheader">
    <div><button id="menubtn" class="menubtn" onMouseover="openNav()">&#9776;</button></div>
  </div>

  <div id="sidenav" class="sidenav" onMouseout="closeNav()">
    <a style="padding-top: 20px" href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `onmouseout` event is firing when you mouse out of one of the children. Use `onmouseleave` instead as it doesn't bubble. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071798/prevent-onmouseout-from-firing-on-child-elements). It really isn't good practice to use inline handlers though. You should instead use the `addEventListener()` method. It would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("sidenav").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){
    closeNav();
});
```

Comment: It worked :) and thanks for the suggestion on not using inline handlers, I'm not very experienced so I'll look more into it.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a CSS approach, rather than a JS approach.

For example, consider removing all JS code. Then, set CSS as following:

```
.sidenav {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sidenav:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```